# How to merge two different classes data into one in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have use two different classes:

*ListTitle.kt*

```
class ListTitle {
    var id: Int? = null
    var title: String? = null

    constructor(id:Int, title: String) {
        this.id = id
        this.title = title
    }
}
```

*ListDes.kt*

```
class ListDes {
    var address: Int? = null
    var des: String? = null

    constructor(address: Int, des: String) {
        this.address = address
        this.des = des
    }
}
```

`listOfTitle` and `listDes` are `ArrayList`s:

```
listOfTitle.add(ListTitle(1, "Hello"))
listOfTitle.add(ListTitle(2, "World"))

listDes.add(ListDes(1, "World Des"))
listDes.add(ListDes(2, "Hello Des"))
```

I want to assign `title` of `ListTitle` to `des` of `ListDes` by matching them by `id`/`address` for each element of the two lists.

How can I approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to show 1 of title into 1 des and 2 title into 2 des"?

Comment: it  means that in the 1 title i want to relate 1 des string and with 2 title to 2 des string

Comment: Why not build a list of Pair?

Comment: @HaarisIqubal welcome on StackOverflow. pls specify the desired output next time, to make more clear what you want to achieve! I posted an answer and I guess it does what you want, but since an example is missing I am not sure. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) to merge two lists into one which has `Pairs` as elements.

```
val listOfTitle = listOf(ListTitle(1, "Hello"), ListTitle(2, "World"))
val listDes = listOf(ListDes(1, "World Des"), ListDes(2, "Hello Des"))

val pairList = listOfTitle.zip(listDes)

// since an element in the new list is a pair, we can use destructuring declaration 
pairList.forEach { (title, des) ->
    println("${title.title} ${des.des}")
}
```

**Output:**

> Hello World Des
> World Hello Des

**A few notes:**

You can write your classes in a shorter form in Kotlin. Just put the properties directly in the argument list of the primary constructor like shown below.

```
class ListTitle(
   var id: Int? = null,
   var title: String? = null
)

class ListDes(
    var address: Int? = null,
    var des: String? = null
)
```

- Don't overuse nullability (using `Int?` instead of `Int` for instance). Make properties only nullable if necessary. If you always pass in arguments for the specified properties there is not need for them to be nullable.
- Maybe you should choose other names for the classes (without "List" in it) since they are actually elements of a `List` in your example and not lists themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the values you could do this:

```
listOfTitle.forEach {
    val id = it.id
    println(it.title + " " + listDes.filter { it.address == id }[0].des)
}
```

will print the matching `des` for each `id`:

```
Hello World Des
World Hello Des
```

The above code is supposed to work when both lists have the same length and there is always a matching `des` for each `id`

if you want to create a new list with the matching pairs:

```
val newList = listOfTitle.map { it ->
    val id = it.id
    Pair(it.title, listDes.filter { it.address == id }[0].des)
}

newList.forEach { println(it.first + " " + it.second) }
```